# Alterando um valor com a biblioteca pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou abrindo um arquivo .csv com a biblioteca pandas, porém me é informado no momento de abertura deste arquivo que uma determinada coluna apresenta valores de tipos diferentes. Sei que o caracter "/" foi utilizado neste arquivo para denotar dado ausente, muito provável que seja este o problema. Minha dúvida é, como substituir o caracter "/"  por outro valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o tipo de dado desejado for numérico, você pode, após abrir o arquivo, fazer isto:

```
df['coluna']=pd.to_numeric(df['coluna'], errors='coerce')
```

Assim, você já converte os valores existentes para número e os '/' para NaN.
Depois se quiser um número no lugar do NaN, pode usar a função fillna() descrita pelo Claudio Gonçalves Filho.

Comment: Oi Paula, muito obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou!!!! Porém, também ocorre situações onde o campo mistura "/" com número, fruto de erro de digitação. Exemplo: "/2.53". Há alguma forma de excluir apenas os caracteres "/"? Ou substituir "/" por vázio ("")?

Comment: Fala Mauricio, você pode usar a função `lstrip()` iterando sobre as colunas   do teu dataframe.  
 **Para uma coluna ficaria :** 
`df['Coluna'] = novodf['Coluna'].str.lstrip('/')`

**Iterando :** 
`for coluna in df.columns: 
                              novodf[coluna] = novodf[coluna].str.lstrip('/')`

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Mauricio, tudo certo?

Acredito que se o pandas estiver identificando a '/' como caractere, tu pode utilizar a função 'apply'.

```
novodf = antigodf.apply(lambda x: x.replace('/','0'))
```

Desta forma tu substituiria a '/' por '0'

Caso deseje substituir a '/' por valor NaN, para assim utilizar funções relacionadas a numeros nulos do pandas, importe a biblioteca numpy e substitua o '0' do apply por np.nan, ficando assim:

```
import numpy as np
novodf = antigodf.apply(lambda x: x.replace('/',np.nan))
```

Caso deseje substituir o NaN, pode utilizar a função `fillna()` passando o valor que ira substituir o NaN

```
novodf.fillna(0)
```

Este comando substituiria os valores NaN por 0.

Segue um link do site do Paulo Vasconcellos com otimas dicas de pandas e data science : [PauloVasconcellos](https://paulovasconcellos.com.br/28-comandos-%C3%BAteis-de-pandas-que-talvez-voc%C3%AA-n%C3%A3o-conhe%C3%A7a-6ab64beefa93)

Espero ter ajudado.

Obrigado.

Claudio.

Comment: Obrigado Claudio!

Comment: Não obtive êxito utilizando a expressão novodf = antigodf.apply(lambda x: x.replace('/','0')). Não ocorre erro de execução, porém não substitui o caracter "/".